# Cross-table foreign key constraints

Tags: django, django-models

Consider the following Django models:

```
class GeneralJournal(models.Model):
    pass

class Journal(models.Model):
    general_journal = models.ForeignKey(GeneralJournal)

class Account(models.Model):
    general_journal = models.ForeignKey(GeneralJournal)
    journals = models.ManyToManyField(Journal)
```

What would be the best way to enforce that the `Account.journals` relationship would only accept journals whose `Journal.general_journal` was the same as the `Account.general_journal`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use [`clean_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean_fields) method of model to validate data of your fields.